# How to add auto hyphens between numbers in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I created input field, when user enter numbers then add auto hyphens.

Format is:

34603-5358722-7

I am using HTML and Javascript

Please share soulution

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you aren't tried anything. Please try to solve first: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to add hyphen `-` after every 5th letter. You can modify it and add hyphen according to your requirement

```js
function formatData(elem) {
  elem.value = elem.value.replace(/(\d{5})(\d{7})/, "$1-$2");

}
```

```html
<input type='text' onkeyup='formatData(this)'>
```